# Center DIV when positioned as absolute, with changing content in the DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, width

I have a website where I have div on the website which is centered both vertically and horizontally. It's current content is *25* and therefor the centering works horizontally. if I change the content I'll have to edit the `width` to it's width and the `margin-left` to half the width. With the content changing everytime you enter the website, this won't work and I need a solution for it.

How could I fix it? Could I maybe **detect** the width of the text and set the `width` & `margin-left` with js or jQuery?

```
#output {
    position: absolute;

    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -160px;

    color: #6FA673;
    font: 200pt Aleo;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 50%;

    width: 296px;
    margin-left: -148px;
}
```

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
Here's a JSFiddle for you guys! Works perfectly with the number 25 but anything else will be a little bit off - vertically.

[JSFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/magnusburton/b4TTK/)

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle.net or codepen.io, with your HTML & CSS please :)

Comment: @GCyrillus Added a JSFiddle, thank you for your rapid response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just saw your jsfiddle, meanwhile i made up something with HTML/CSS , trying to figure out what you looked for (to me simlar to lightbox :) )

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dgKls

From your jsfiddle 
this ? http://jsfiddle.net/b4TTK/13/

```
#output, html, body {

    height:100%;

    width:100%;

    margin:0;

    display:table;

}

body {

    display:table-cell;

    vertical-align:middle;

    text-align:center;

}

#output {

    position: absolute;

    color: #6FA673;

    font: 200pt Arial;

    font-weight: bold;

    line-height:0

}
```

not as fluid though

Comment: Not the shortest solution but it does what should. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

You said...

> if I change the content I'll have to edit the width to it's width and
>   the margin-left to half the width.

...No you don't have to do that.  You just need a better CSS solution.  An alternative approach is to simply center the content no matter how long or short your text content is.  Then you wouldn't have to worry about writing up js code to detect it's css properties...

The CSS:

```
   #output {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        margin:0 auto;

        text-align:center;
        color: #6FA673;
        font: 200pt Arial;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
```

And my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blackhawx/b4TTK/12/)

**update**
You can vertically align your element on page load with a simple jquery approach...

The JS:

```
var mtop = $(window).height()/2;
$('#output').css({top: mtop});
```

Comment: With the position set to relative it's not centering the div vertically, thanks for your great answer though.

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is that the margin-left needs to be 1/2 the width of the contanier, you can use the following:

```
$('#output').css('marginLeft', '-'+$('#output').width() /2+'px');
```

And of course

```
width: auto;
```

Comment: I might have not explained myself too well in the question. I need to detect the width of the text and then later set the width & the margin-left values. Thanks though for your code, will be useful when I've detected the width.